# Vue.js 2 & webpack / npm start opens and reloads in FF instead of Chrome

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I am following the Vue.js tutorial "The Ultimate Vue JS 2 Developers Course"(Project 2) and I am running into an issue with the browser refresh on file change. I am on Kubuntu 16.04 and my system's standard browser is Chrome, but yet, every time I change a file in my project, webpack tries to open Firefox, which is not installed on my system (and I don't want to use Firefox, but Chrome).

I already went through the webpack.config.js, but I just can't figure out, where I could change settings for the browser.

**webpack.config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/main.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            "presets": [ [ "env" ] ],
            "plugins": [ "transform-es2015-destructuring", "transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-runtime" ]
          }
        }],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this nessessary.
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
            'js': 'babel-loader?presets[]=env'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  module.exports.plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ];
  module.exports.entry.push('webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000'); //?noInfo=true&quiet=true)
  module.exports.module.rules[0].use.push({ loader: 'webpack-module-hot-accept' });
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map';
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

**webpack-dev-middleware.js**

```
const webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

module.exports = {
  init(app) {
    app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
      hot: true,
      stats: {
        colors: true
      },
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
      filename: webpackConfig.output.filename,
    }));

    app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler, {
      log: console.log,
      path: '/__webpack_hmr',
      heartbeat: 10 * 1000,
    }));
  }
};
```

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config({ silent: true });

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const api = require('./api');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  require('./webpack-dev-middleware').init(app);
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
}

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

let template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./index.html'), 'utf-8');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(template);
});

app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
  api.getData(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.json(data);
    }
  });
});

let offlineData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./api_offline.json'), 'utf-8'));
app.get('/offline_api', function(req, res) {
  let data = offlineData.find(item => item.imdbID === req.query.i);
  if (!data) {
    data = { "Response":"False", "Error":`IMDb ID ${req.query.i} not found.` }
  }
  res.json(data);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`);
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    require('open')(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
  }
});
```

When I open the url in Chrome, I am able to see the page, but it doesn't refresh automatically when a file changes. Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vue-cinema",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The Ultimate Vue.js Developers Course: Vue.js Cinema",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "Anthony Gore <anthony@vuejsdevelopers.com>",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/vuejsdevelopers/vuejs-cinema"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./server.js --ignore src/ -e js,html,css",
    "build": "rimraf dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.3",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.20.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "uglify-js": "^3.0.28",
    "vue": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.14.0",
    "webpack-module-hot-accept": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

yuriy636's answer did the trick: I added 'google-chrome' as he suggested, and now it works. Thanks!

This is the updated part in **server.js**:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`);
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    require("open")(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`, 'google-chrome');
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of your `package.json` too? The project probably has there the launch script of the dev-server, and with that we could pass a parameter in order to open in another browser: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-open

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help. I will post the package.json file:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is using the `open` library in order to open a URL in a browser. Specifically this line, in `server.js` file:

```js
require('open')(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
```

[`open`](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open#usage) accepts a second optional argument as the program used to open the URL

```js
require('open')(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`, 'google-chrome');
```

---

There is a lack of documentation about what string to pass, [another library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn#app) mentions that it depends on the OS:

> The app name is platform dependent. Don't hard code it in reusable
>   modules. For example, Chrome is **google chrome** on macOS, **google-chrome**
>   on Linux and **chrome** on Windows.

So try other strings if "google-chrome" doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and report back if it worked!